# Allowing audio files with pronunciaton

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Ist es möglich das Hochladen von Audiodateien (z.B. um die Aussprache zu erklären) zu erlauben?

How possible would it be to allow uploading audio files for pronunciation purposes?

Comment: What for? You can use IPA or link to an existing pronunciation. In which cases you need to upload an audio file?

Comment: Da haben Sie recht @Em1. Obwohl das für andere Sprachen nützlich sein könnte, Deutsche Aussprache ist regelmäßig genug.